# exit a view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview

how do i programmatically exit a view in an iPhone app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question… I can interpret it a few ways:

1) How do I dismiss a view controller manually in a Navigation Controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

2) How do I dismiss a modal view controller manually in a Navigation Controller

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

3) Remove a view from the view hierarchy

```
[theView removeFromSuperview];
```

4) How do I programmatically exit the app

```
exit(0);
```